# Como criar link para chamar o resource destroy?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma view blade com a seguinte estrutura:

```
@forelse($posts as $p)
<tr>
    <td><a href="/post/{{ $p->id }}">{{ $p->titulo }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ $p->status_mutator }}</td>
    <td>{{ $p->user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $p->created_at->format('d/m/Y à\s H:i:s')}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}/edit">Editar</a> / 
        <a href="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}">Excluir</a>
    </td>
</tr>
@empty
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">Não existem posts para serem listados</td>
</tr>
@endforelse
```

Mas minha rota utiliza a estrutura resource, ou seja, tenho que submeter a opção de Excluir via método DELETE. Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Excluir algo por meio de um simples link é inseguro. Melhor você criar um formulário, definir o método "DELETE" para a rota e utilizar um botão ou um evento em um link que submeta o formulário

Comment: Sim a ideia é essa. Conforme havia dito quero utilizar o método DELETE (verbo DELETE) via form. Só preciso de ajuda para construir algo em JavaScript que capture o id do link clicado e submeta o form

Answer (score 1):

Você deve trocar o link por um formulário, da seguinte forma:

Substitua isso:

```
<td>
        <a href="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}/edit">Editar</a>  
        <a href="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}">Excluir</a>
    </td>
```

Por isso:

```
<td>
    <a href="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}/edit">Editar</a>  
    <form actio="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}" ...>
        <button type="submit">Excluir</buttom>
    </form>
</td>
```

Se por questão de estilo você quer manter o link. Você deve capturar o evento de clique do link e submeter o formulário dinamicamente.

Supondo que você utilize jQuery, o código vai ser +- esse(Não testei):

HTML:

```
<td>
    <a href="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}/edit">Editar</a> / 
    <form actio="/painel/post/{{ $p->id }}">
        <a href="#" class="link-delete">Excluir</a>
    </form>
</td>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

   $(".link-delete").click(function(event){
      $(event.target).parent().submit();
   });

</script>
```

**UPDATE**
Já ia me esquecendo. O metodo DELETE não é suportado pelo HTML em formulário. Então você deve postar, por meio de um campo do tipo "hidden" o método utilizado. +- Assim.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode também utilizar um callback Javascript para fazer isso utilizando o Fetch:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="deletarPost('{{ $p->id }}')">...</a>
```

```js
function deletarPost(id) {
    fetch('/painel/post/' + id, { method: 'DELETE' })
        .then(() => alert("Deletado com sucesso!");
}
```